# Display json object in angularjs codemirror

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ui-codemirror

I have a json object and want to display it on codemirror using angularjs codemirror but it got an error saying `ui-codemirror cannot use an object or an array as a model`. Then I tried to convert the object into string using `JSON.stringify`, the string does not format nicely in codemirror. Anyone can help me to figure out how to make my code in formatted nicely in codemirror?
Thanks

ex:

```
//inside javascript

    $scope.code = {
        "name": "user1",
        "id": "34",
        "value": [3, 5, 4]
    };
    
     $scope.editorOptions = {
          lineWrapping : true,
          lineNumbers: true,
          mode: 'application/json',
        };

//inside html
<ui-codemirror ui-codemirror-opts="editorOptions" ng-model="code"></ui-codemirror>
```

It returns an error for this: ui-codemirror cannot use an object or an array as a model

if I change to `JSON.stringify($scope.code)`, code mirror display like this:

> {"name":"user1","id":"34","value":[3,5,4]}

However, I want it to display as this:

> {
>
> ```
>       "name": "user1",
>       "id": "34",
>       "value": [3, 5, 4]
>     }
> ```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: `JSON.stringify($scope.code,null, '\t')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the indentation:

```
$scope.codeView = JSON.stringify($scope.code, null, 4);
```

[Live example](http://plnkr.co/edit/85ZjHz28SgzLgFuUgBdl?p=preview)

Comment: How can we get expand/collapse for a section of json, similar to something we see in an online json viewer